# Get Email from user and enter into SharePoint list field

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate

I have a SharePoint list where I use a field Person or Group to enter an Employee's name.

The second column is their email address which I enter manually. Is it possible to fill this field automatically with their email address and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

You can create a workflow or Microsoft flow/power automate to update the Email address field based on the Person or Group field.

**Solution 2**:

If you are not going to use those email address values later (you don't need to save emails in column) and you just want to show the email in SharePoint list view then you can also achieve it using JSON column formatting.

1. Create one single line of text column.
2. Hide it from list forms (make it **Hidden** from content type settings).
3. Then use below JSON code to format the column:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "[$PersonGroupCol.email]"
}
```

Where `PersonGroupCol` is internal name of person or group field. You can get the internal name of your person or group column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Solution 2 was a really clever approach! Just wondering why you are hiding the column?

Comment: If you don't want to enter it manually fro list form then you probably wants to hide it from list forms. if you are okay with field being visible on forms then keep it that way.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that by using 2nd approach we are just showing the email in list view. not actually saving the values in list column (email column).

Comment: Ah yes of course, I should have read it again. I though you were hiding it from the list view...

Comment: Nice solution, but will not work when user exports data to Excel, which might me one of the use cases. Try to use Flow or PowerBI instead.

Comment: Yes, that is what I explained in my answer. If you want to save value in email column & then use it somewhere else then you have to update the email column using workflow/Power Automate flow on item creation/update.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Ganesh Sanap](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/69998/ganesh-sanap)’s **Solution 1**, here’s a sample flow for your reference.

[image]

There is one **dynamic content** called `PersonGroupCol Email`, which you can directly use to update the Email column. (Where `PersonGroupCol` is internal name of person or group field.)

Not as good as the **Solution 2** but it is doable.

Comment: Thanks, i tried solution 1 with the flow and it works! I will try solution  2 also, just for practice. I also tried the trigger, When a item is selected. However, that does not work. I have over a 100 items that need to be updated with the emailadresses. So, is there a way around making an manual change to all the items first?

Comment: @Mirte Solution 2 is the better one actually since it updates the column in time – as soon as you fill in/modify the person or group column. If you want to bulk update item properties, you may consider using PowerShell: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/07/sharepoint-online-update-list-items-using-powershell.html

Comment: Doesn't this result in an infinite loop? The trigger is when an item is added or updates, and the 'action' is updating the said item. Which is going to cause an update which triggers this flow again... and so on.