# Is it possible to get email from person column in SharePoint calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Is it possible to get email from person column in SharePoint calculated column?

Please write it, if it is possible.

Comment: What is the use case exactly? Can you explain your requirements in detail so that we can suggest workaround?

Comment: Hi @Chandrika, Does my solution given below work for you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (by clicking the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **No**.

You cannot use person or group column values in SharePoint calculated columns.

It is a known behavior of SharePoint calculated columns.

---

You can find some workarounds like using Power automate flow or SharePoint JSON formatting to get email address from person or group column and show it in another column at: [Get Email from user and enter into SharePoint list field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278295/get-email-from-user-and-enter-into-sharepoint-list-field/278296#278296)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a column to display the user's email address? If so, you can build a column of single-line text and format this column.

1.Create a single line text column and format this column.
[image]

2.Switch to Advanced mode.

[image]

3.Please attention that "people" is the column name of Person column. Please replace your name:
There is the JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$people.email]"
}
```

4.Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: This is an exact same solution provided in "link" given in my answer below :)